# I don't know why request.compile() dosen't work

Tags: python

I don't have any files named re or requests in my source code directory.

The function 're.compile()' worked well a few days ago, but suddenly this error happens.

```
import requests as re
p = re.compile('[a-z]+')
m = p.search("python")
print(m)
```

---

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7864\2076162965.py in <module>
      1 import requests as re
----> 2 p = re.compile('[a-z]+')
      3 m = p.search("python")
      4 print(m)

AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'compile'
```

So i deleted and reinstall requests library and checked how this code works, but same error happens.

Comment: `import re` https://pynative.com/python-regex-compile/.  Regex != Requests

Comment: `requests` is a library that supports HTTP requests. `re` is a library that supports regular expressions. The line `import requests as re` imports the first but gives it the name of the second. As the error message clearly explains,  the `requests` module does not offer a `compile()` function. That function is in the *real* `re` function. Don't do `import requests as re`. Do `import re` and your code will work as you expect.

Comment: And *never* reinstall modules from the standard library. That indicates you believe that the fault is with the standard library and not with your code. Until you rid yourself of that belief you will never find the bugs in your code.